# Is JSON not serialise-able over http or Django doesn't know how to read it?

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have created a couple of projects with Django.

Every time  I try to send an ajax POST request from frontend to django, I have to use JSON.stringify() function, pass it inside the body of POST request and parse the JSON manually inside Django (using ujson, because of its faster).

My question is that why do I need to do this manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what manual steps you're seeing here that you would expect to be automatic. What should be different?

Comment: I was hoping that i could do
data: {'foo': 'bar'} 
while sending the js post request

and 
request.POST.get('foo') in django

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the standard way or not, but this seemed pretty intuitive to me. Get requests seem to work this way 

(using request.GET.get('foo'))

Comment: But then it wouldn't be JSON, it would just be standard form-encoded data. You certainly can do that, if it's basic data and you don't care what format it's sent in.

Comment: Ah, right got it. I thought form-encoded data and JSON were the same. Thanks for clearing that up.